# Using Join to get data from multiple tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join

```
A(a_id, a1, a2)
B(b_id, b1, b2)
C(c-id, a_id, b_id)
```

Now, I want to fetch all the data of `table A`, and from `table B`, I only need a record of `b1`. How can I use join query in SQL Server to fetch the desired data?

Comment: `I want to to fetch all the data of table A, and from table B` -> Left Outer Join is what you are looking for. Check [this visual poster](http://stevestedman.com/2015/05/tsql-join-types-poster-version-4/) to help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to `JOIN` table `A` and `B`, but the configuration is on table `C`:

```
SELECT
    A.*,
    B.b1
FROM db.A
JOIN db.C ON (C.a_id=A.a_id)
JOIN db.B ON (B.b_id=C.b_id)
WHERE `table`.`field` = `parameter` # <-- Aditional
```